# QCQP Convex quadratic optimisation with quadratic constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, qcqp, cvx

I am trying to implement this QCQP optimisation problem in a more efficient way.

The optimisation aims to smooth an existing 3D trajectory represented by "P" which contains "n" 3D coordinates. The "n" variables called "Q" are initialised to be equal to "P". We want therefore optimise those 3D coordinates according to the following constraints and objective function:

\begin{align}
\min_{Q_3,\ldots,Q_{n-2}} \quad& \sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\|2Q_k-Q_{k-1}-Q_{k+1}\|^2\\
\mathrm{s.t.} \quad & Q_1=P_1, \quad Q_2 = P_1 + d\cdot\frac{v_1}{\|v_1\|}\\
\quad &Q_n = P_n,\quad Q_{n-1} = P_n - d\cdot\frac{v_{n-1}}{\|v_{n-1}\|}\\
\quad &Q_k\in\mathcal B_k, \quad k=3,\ldots, n-1\\
\quad& \|2Q_k-Q_{k-1}-Q_{k+1}\|\leqslant\min\left\{\frac{d^2}{R_{\mathrm{min}}}, \alpha_k\left(\frac d{v_k}\right)^2\right\}, \quad k=2,\ldots,n-1.
\end{align}

I have managed to implement this in Matlab using CVX but now I need better performances to work in real time. I was trying to convert my code from Matlab to C++ but CVX does not support Matlab Coder so that the only solution would be either to use a different matlab toolbox that supports it or better a c++ library to solve this problem directly.

I don't have much experience in this field and I find very difficult to implement it in matrix form and without a user-friendly interface.

I would be grateful for any help

thanks

Comment: I have written your formulation in MathJax but please check it for errors. The image was low-resolution and thus difficult to read.

Comment: if you are solving a series pf problems differing only in the numerical values of the input data, you should get some speedup vs. CVX by using YALMIP's "optimizer"  https://yalmip.github.io/command/optimizer/ object capability.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Sorry for the confusion. I have just edited the question to make everything more clear.

Comment: @Math1000 where can I check this? thanks

Comment: Here is a tutorial on MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference